# How do I repeatedly call a method on a single object?

Tags: java, object

I am trying to do this task:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Message m = new Message("test");
    m.append(" in").append(" progress").append(" ... ");
    m.printMessage();

    // Returns test in progress ...

}
```

Where I create an object m and call an append method created in the class on the object three times. I understand that the method has to return a "Message" object in order to call the method on it again, but how do I make it so that when I call the append method, which takes a String type as an input and adds it to the message passed to the object when created, it will use only the existing object created?

Comment: take a look at `StringBuilder`: `new StringBuilder("test").append(" in").append(" progress")`

Comment: Looking up the Builder pattern may be useful.

Comment: for the record there is the `StringBuilder` that does exactly what you want - and is using exactly this technique under the hood

Answer (score 2):

In the `Message.append()` method, return `this` to return the current instance such as:

```
public Message append(String msg){
   // use msg
   return this;
}
```

---

As mentioned by others, you have also built-in ways to concatenate `String`s to a specific object and return this object itself. 
`StringBuilder` that represents a mutable sequence of characters is a common way.

1) If you notice that you don't need any longer the `Message` class you could remove it and use instead of a `StringBuilder` instance such as :

```
StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder("test");
m.append(" in").append(" progress").append(" ... ");
```

Note that in this case you should so create a `printMessage()` somewhere else that could look like :

```
public void printMessage(StringBuilder m){
  ...
}
```

2) Alternatively, if the  `Message` class is all the same required, you could keep it and delegate/wrap in internal a `StringBuilder` instance such as :

```
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
public Message append(String msg){
   builder.append(msg); 
   return this;
}
```

Comment: I read 3 times his post until i understood what he askead  :D

Comment: It returns exactly the same object.  Its state has been modified, but it's the same object.

Comment: It returns the current instance of `Message`. So if you modify its state for example by using the `msg` parameter, you will return the `Message` instance with the updated state.

Comment: @davidxxx for the record mentioning `StringBuilder` here would be good for the OP too; for you though, if you want, look for type safe builder in java-8 pattern...

Comment: @Eugene Right. I had avoided this point as the requirement is rather broad. I updated. It could be helpful probably.

Comment: @Eugene What do you mean by "type safe builder in java-8 pattern." ? If you have a reference, share it please :)

Comment: @davidxxx np. http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2014/11/02/builder-pattern-with-java-8-lambdas/ you can also read federico's combinator's here https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-combinators-part-1

Comment: @Eugene  Thanks. Looks interesting. It will give me good reading for tomorrow :)